Green's function in General Relativity: when can we express the Ricci tensor as an operator?
One can express the Riemann tensor acting on a vector field $V^\mu$ as
$$R^\sigma_{\mu\rho\nu} V^\mu = \left(\nabla_\rho\nabla_\nu - \nabla_\nu\nabla_\rho\right)V^\sigma,$$
so we must be able to express the Ricci tensor as such a thing as well
$$R_{\mu\nu}V^\mu = R^\rho_{\mu\rho\nu} V^\mu = \left(\nabla_\rho\nabla_\nu - \nabla_\nu\nabla_\rho\right)V^\rho.$$
My question is, could we express the Einstein field equations in term of this type of operator? The result would be something like (renaming $\rho \longrightarrow \mu$)
$$\left(\nabla_\mu\nabla_\nu - \nabla_\nu\nabla_\mu - \frac{1}{2}Rg_{\mu\nu} - \kappa T_{\mu\nu}\right)V^\mu = 0. \tag{1}\label{1}$$
Is this useful to find a Green's function to the equations of motion of general relativity in the general case? There should also be a Green's function in these field equations other than with linearised gravity, where $g_{\mu\nu}$ cannot be approximated by $g_{\mu\nu} = \eta_{\mu\nu} + h_{\mu\nu}$ such that $\left|\left|h_{\mu\nu}\right|\right| \ll 1$.
Is this the case and a Green's function to (\ref{1}) would be that for the general  case?

Consider the definition of the Ricci scalar requiring the presence of the metric. Also, I’m not sure why you’d really wat to render the EFEs in terms of dozens and dozens of covariant derivatives in various directions.

If you choose spin frames you can write the Ricci scalar as an operator easily. See schrodinger-licnerowicz formula.

From there you can vary the action and get what youre looking for

I think you might be missing the point. The fact that a differential operator ends up actually being an algebraic operator is remarkable. You might expect that  the value of $\left(\nabla_\rho\nabla_\nu - \nabla_\nu\nabla_\rho\right)V^\sigma$ at a point would depend on how the vector field $V$ varies in the neighborhood of that point, but it doesn’t.

In other words, the left side of your first equation is a massive simplification of the right side.

Following Ghoster's insightful comment, it is clear that we cannot find a general Green's function for the Einstein field equations (EFEs).
According to our previous definition of $R^\sigma_{\mu\rho\nu}$ acting on $V^\mu$, we can consider an operator definition for the Riemann tensor of the form
$$R^\sigma_{\mu\rho\nu} = \left[\nabla_\rho, \nabla_\nu\right]\delta^\sigma_\mu,$$
because
$$R^\sigma_{\mu\rho\nu}V^\mu = \left[\nabla_\rho, \nabla_\nu\right]\delta^\sigma_\mu V^\mu = \left[\nabla_\rho, \nabla_\nu\right]V^\sigma,$$
which is exactly the definition of $R^\sigma_{\mu\rho\nu}$ in the post. We can then contract it to find the Ricci tensor as
$$R_{\mu\nu} = R^\sigma_{\mu\sigma\nu} = \left[\nabla_\sigma, \nabla_\nu\right]\delta^\sigma_\mu = \left[\nabla_\mu, \nabla_\nu\right],$$
and thus the Ricci scalar would also be
$$R = g^{\mu\nu}R_{\mu\nu} = \left[\nabla^\nu, \nabla_\nu\right] = \left[\nabla_\mu, \nabla^\mu\right].$$
The problem is that $R$ is a scalar, not an operator, so in principle we cannot express it as such a commutator of operators. Note that, due to indices renaming,
$$\left[\nabla^\nu, \nabla_\nu\right] = -\left[\nabla_\mu, \nabla^\mu\right],$$
so if $\left[\nabla^\nu, \nabla_\nu\right] = \left[\nabla_\mu, \nabla^\mu\right]$ then it is necessary that $\left[\nabla^\nu, \nabla_\nu\right]=\left[\nabla_\mu, \nabla^\mu\right]=0$. But since $R \neq 0$ in the general case, then we cannot express $R$ as an operator.
Thus, the fact that —as Ghoster remarks— the Riemann tensor contracted with a vector turns out to be equal to a commutator of covariant derivatives for the Levi-Civita connection does not imply that they are equal. This is true especially in the case of the Ricci scalar, where its representation as a commutator of operators is a bit clumsy.
The consequence is that we cannot find a "general" Green's function for the EFEs. Otherwise, they should act on a metric tensor $g_{\mu\nu}$ as
$$\left(R^{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2}Rg^{\mu\nu} - \Lambda g^{\mu\nu} - \kappa T^{\mu\nu}\right)g_{\mu\nu} = \left(R_{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2}Rg_{\mu\nu} - \Lambda g_{\mu\nu} - \kappa T_{\mu\nu}\right)g^{\mu\nu} = 0,$$
which unfolds to become
$$\left[\nabla_\mu, \nabla^\mu\right] - 2\left[\nabla_\mu, \nabla^\mu\right] -4\Lambda - \kappa T = 0,$$
or
$$R + 4\Lambda + \kappa T = 0.$$
This is not a differential equation. When $R^{\mu\nu}$ or $T_{\mu\nu}$ act on $g_{\mu\nu}$ they cannot be conceived as operators, but rather simply as tensors. Note that $\left[\nabla^\mu, \nabla^\nu\right]g_{\mu\nu} \neq 0$ does only make sense if and only if $\left[\nabla^\mu, \nabla^\nu\right]$ acts as a tensor rather than as an operator due to metric compatibility.

I'm not sure what insight you are talking about but the commutator expression for Ricci tensor and Ricci scalar is wrong. Ricci is a symmetric tensor and so the commutation doesn't make sense. Ricci Scalar is a scalar but what you wrote means it's identically zero

That’s the idea: it doesn’t make sense. That’s why there is no Green’s function for the generic EFEs, so the metric tensor’s “equations of motion” have not an associated Green’s function, at least not for arbitrary $g_{\mu\nu}$
